# Trim aac-mp4 audio in android (mediaCodec/extractor)

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I want to trim an existing aac-mp4 audio file. For the first time I want to "trim" 0 bytes, basically just to copy the file using MediaCodec/MediaExtractor.

Questions:

1. The header is fixed size and I can just copy it from the old file? Or it has some infos about the track duration and I need to update it? If it has fixed size which is that (in order to know how many bytes should I copy from the old file)?
2. Should I only use the extractor's getSampleData(ByteBuffer, offset) and advance() or I should also use the MediaCodec and extract the samples(decode) and then encode them again with an encoder - and write the encoded values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you use MediaExtractor, you probably aren't going to read the raw file yourself, so I don't see what header you're proposing to copy. This is probably easiest to do with MediaExtractor + MediaMuxer; just copy the MediaFormat and the packets you get from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer.
2. This depends on how you want to do the trimming. It's absolutely simplest to not involve MediaCodec at all, but just copy packets from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer, and skip the packets at the start that you want to omit (or use `seekTo()` for seeking to the right start position).

But keep in mind that audio frames have a certain length; for AAC-LC it's usually 1024 samples, which for 48 kHz audio is 21 milliseconds. So if you only copy individual packets, you can't get any closer trimming granularity than 21 milliseconds, for 48 kHz. This probably is fine for most cases, but if the audio has a lower sample rate, say 8 kHZ, the granularity ends up as high as 128 ms.

If you want to trim to a more exact position than the individual packets allow you, you need to decode using MediaCodec, skip the right amount of samples, repackage output frames from the decoder into new full frames for the encoder, and encode this.

Comment: Thanks, I know the sample rate since my app also records those file that will be trimmed (so I have full control over the sample rate which in my case is 48 kHz). The trimming is per second (forced from GUI controls) so the granularity is not a problem. I thought that mp4-aac has a header just like a PCM-WAV has (for wav-pcm I already completed the trimming task, it was simply for me to do it since I know very well this format - no need for extractor there, I only copied audio frames from point A to point B)nand updated the header with new length

Comment: I don't know much about MediaMuxer, but why I need it since I can get the   encoded data from the extractor? Also, I can use getSampleTime() to see the time of the current encoded sample (or just seekTo())...Isn't enough to write the sampleData retrieved from the extractor via getSampleData()?

Comment: If you want to create an mp4 file, you can't just copy a header and write the raw packet data to the file, you need MediaMuxer or a similar library to do this, since mp4 files have got a much more complicated structure than pcm-wav. If you create ADTS AAC files, you can pretty much just write the raw packet data though, but MediaExtractor doesn't (in most cases) provide data in this form, you'd need to add a small header to each packet.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I will use MediaMuxer, it appears to be pretty simple, I saw a few examples already.

Comment: Also of note is that MediaExtractor is pretty slow. If you are trimming an AAC ADTS file, you can do it much faster by just scanning the file yourself.